# Image transformations to correctly OCR embossed text?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I have been trying to perform OCR on a set of images of manufacturing parts with embossed text. Here are example images:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

The part seems to have a rough surface so transformations and image processing techniques like thresholding don't give clear distinction between the background and the text. Therefore `pytesseract` is not able to give correct answer.

Here's the code of the techniques I've tried so far:

```py
image= cv2.imread('image.jpg')
darker= cv2.equalizeHist(image)
darker=darker[180:350, 200:450]
cv2_imshow(darker)
thresh = cv2.threshold(darker, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY| cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cv2_imshow(thresh)
# adaptiveThresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(darker, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 35, 30)
# inverted_bin=cv2.bitwise_not(adaptiveThresh)
# cv2_imshow(inverted_bin)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
processed_img = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations = 1)
processed_img = cv2.dilate(processed_img, kernel, iterations = 1)
cv2_imshow(processed_img)

img_roi = image[75:150, 75:150]
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img_roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2_imshow(gray_img)
gray_img.shape

# Gaussian Blur
Gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_img, (5, 5), 0)
cv2_imshow(Gaussian)

# Median Blur
median = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img, 5)
cv2_imshow(median)

# # Bilateral Blur
bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray_img, 9, 75, 75)
cv2_imshow(bilateral)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_img, lang='eng', config='--psm 7.5')
print("result: ", text)
```

I am using `Pytesseract` and have so far tried thresholding (Binary_INV and OTSU's Thresholding), Gaussian blurring, Median blurring, Histograms Equalization, erosion, dilation and Canny Edge detection all from OpenCV library, but none of them seem to enhance the text in the image enough for pytesseract to give correct results.
One of the results for OCR on the equalizeHist + OTSU thresholded image:

> result:  KGdED

Can someone please suggest any possible image transformations/processing methods that can help in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: *"I have been trying to ..."*, Please post your efforts into solving the problem in terms of code [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @bhomaidan90 Attached the code snippets for reference.